# How to create a table like the following?

Tags: tables

I want to create the following table without the estimated value(only two columns), I'm unsure what to do:

[image]

**EDIT:**

Since my table is longer than the one in the picture, is there a way to split it into two(4 columns) like:

Parameter Description    | Parameter Description \[1ex]
A         blah blah blah | \mu     blah blah blah

Comment: Please show us the code you have tried so far!

Comment: @Mensch I haven't tried anything so far because I don't know how to start..

Comment: Hi Math and [welcome to TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436). In its current form, your question might not receive many answers. Please take a look at the [How to Ask](//tex.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask)-page and try to improve your question according to the guidance found there. This may require you to show some effort on your part in terms of attempting a solution. If you have questions about what to do or if you don't quite understand what this means, please ask for clarification using the `add comment` function.

Answer (score 1):

Using just a basic table

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lp{2in}}
\toprule
Parameter & Description\\
\midrule
$A$ & Recruitment rate of the\newline population\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Per your edit:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{tabular}{lp{1.5in}lp{1.5in}}
\toprule
Parameter & Description & Parameter & Description\\
\midrule
$A$ & Recruitment rate of the population & $B$ & Transmission coefficient\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

See https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Tables for a good tutorial on making tables.

Comment: Thank you very much for this solution. is there a way to have a line going down the table between description and parameter as per my edit?

Comment: @Math Yes it is possible. It seems you are new to making tables in LaTeX. I would really recommend you read https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Tables (it is not that long). It will give you a good starting point and you will find how to do this and more.

Comment: I will have a read. But I hope you can solve my issue for now. Also, how do we attach the caption below the table?

Answer (score 0):

```
\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{ll} \hline
 &    \\ \hline
 &    \\
 &    \\
 &
```

and so on...
finish with

```
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{}
\end{table}
```

worst case - use
https://www.tablesgenerator.com/

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!